# Disable spring security in spring boot 2.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to disable spring security in spring boot 2.0.2 by adding the `security.ignore=/**` property but It's not working with me.

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smile
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# suppress inspection "SpringBootApplicationProperties"
security.ignored=/**
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Add this Java Annotations in your main file spring boot application.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
})
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. (Spring Boot 2.1.5, spring-security-web 4.2.3.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-actuator). Did you have to do anything else?

Comment: Try this: @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: This doesn't works when Security is coming from Parent project. Any guidance ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` was not available for me to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

For me this did the Trick (similar to the answer of @wilmer-villca):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```